# How to create a loop in command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I tried this command

```
for /r %v in (*.abc) do abcconvert -toOgawa %v %v
```

and my result is :

```
E:\PROGRAMMES\HOUDINI\bin>abcconvert -toOgawa E:\PROGRAMMES\HOUDINI\bin\Mesh01_00009.abc E:\PROGRAMMES\HOUDINI\bin\ParticleMesh01_00009.abc
Error: inFile and outFile must not be the same!
```

I just wrote one loop but its the same answer for all my loops.

I think my loop is good but i don't know how to change the name of my outfile.. i would like exactly the same path but just newfile0001 then newfile0002 and so on.. for example

I try to do this because i have a lot of files to convert and the original command to do this is :

```
abcconvert -toOgawa file.abc newfile.abc
```

Comment: Are all the files named similarly, `AlphaNumericStringWithoutUnderscores_NumericString.abc`?

Comment: yes exactly,ParticleMesh01_000000.abc then ParticleMesh01_000001.abc then
ParticleMesh01_000002.abc
ParticleMesh01_000003.abc etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good news: your loop works good.
The problem is `%v %v`, which is the very same filename for input and output.
You have to change it somehow. See `for /f` near the end there are "modifiers".

There are many ways to change the output file name, many of them can be done just with those modifiers.

Simplest way: just change the extension:

```
for /r %v in (*.abc) do abcconvert -toOgawa %v %~dpnv.new
```

> ParticleMesh01_000000.new

But you can also add a string to the filename (before the extension):

```
for /r %v in (*.abc) do abcconvert -toOgawa %v %~dpnv-new%~xv
```

> ParticleMesh01_000000-new.abc

Comment: Thank you a lot ! it was exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: If i want to keep the exact same name file but change the path of the output what whill be the new command ? for example a new directory in the same path.. I don't find the answer with the modifiers

Comment: modifiers are `d`rive, `p`ath, `n`ame and e`x`tension. So `%%~d<new_path>%%~nx` should do. Replace `%%~d` with a drive letter (like `E:`) too, if the destination drive is different.